# How can I get a mean ROC curve from multiple Classify iterations?

Tags: plotting, machine-learning

I'm running a classifier on some data using `Classify`. Because the classifier results depend on the data used for training, I decided to run the classifier in a loop with n iterations (each time training and testing with a different subset of the data). This allows me to obtain the average accuracy and average number of correctly and incorrectly classified objects for each group.

Example (with mock data):

```
GroupA = RandomReal[{1, 3}, 100];
GroupB = RandomReal[{2, 4}, 100];
GroupC = RandomReal[{3.5, 6}, 100];

nmax = 100;  (* number of iterations *)
Accurate = {};
AA = {};
AB = {};
AC = {};
BA = {};
BB = {};
BC = {};
CA = {};
CB = {};
CC = {};

For[z = 1, z <= nmax, z++,
  GroupATrain = RandomSample[GroupA, 50];
  GroupATest = Complement[GroupA, GroupATrain];
  
  GroupBTrain = RandomSample[GroupB, 50];
  GroupBTest = Complement[GroupB, GroupBTrain];
  
  GroupCTrain = RandomSample[GroupC, 50];
  GroupCTest = Complement[GroupC, GroupCTrain];
  
  training = <|"A" -> GroupATrain, "B" -> GroupBTrain, 
    "C" -> GroupCTrain|>;
  GroupClass = Classify[training, Method -> {"NearestNeighbors"}];
  
  test = <|"A" -> GroupATest, "B" -> GroupBTest, "C" -> GroupCTest|>;
  CM = ClassifierMeasurements[GroupClass, test];
  
  Accurate = 
   AppendTo[Accurate, CM["Accuracy", ComputeUncertainty -> True]];
  AA = AppendTo[AA, Length[CM["Examples" -> {"A", "A"}]]];
  AB = AppendTo[AB, Length[CM["Examples" -> {"A", "B"}]]];
  AC = AppendTo[AC, Length[CM["Examples" -> {"A", "C"}]]];
  BA = AppendTo[BA, Length[CM["Examples" -> {"B", "A"}]]];
  BB = AppendTo[BB, Length[CM["Examples" -> {"B", "B"}]]];
  BC = AppendTo[BC, Length[CM["Examples" -> {"B", "C"}]]];
  CA = AppendTo[CA, Length[CM["Examples" -> {"C", "A"}]]];
  CB = AppendTo[CB, Length[CM["Examples" -> {"C", "B"}]]];
  CC = AppendTo[CC, Length[CM["Examples" -> {"C", "C"}]]];
  ];
```

The problem I'm having is that I have no idea how to obtain an average ROC curve for each class. I know I can get an ROC curve with the following command:

```
ClassifierMeasurements[GroupClass, test, "ROCCurve"]
```

However, this would only give me the ROC curves for the last iteration. Further, because the result of this is a string of images, there is no point creating an empty string of ROC curves and appending the result in each iteration (as I did with the accuracy and number of correct & incorrect classifications).

Any help on how to get the average ROC curve for each group would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 13.2, it's interesting to see [`NetMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetMeasurements.html) has `"ROCCurvePlot"` for the plot and `"ROCCurve"` for values but [`ClassifierMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClassifierMeasurements.html) only has `"ROCCurve"`. This can not stop us from extracting points from the graphics.

The following function accepts a `"ROCCurve"` and extracts its curve points.

```
ClearAll[ExtractROCPoints];

ExtractROCPoints[g_] :=
  First @ Cases[g, 
    GraphicsComplex[x_, ___] :> 
     DeleteDuplicates @ Complement[x, {{1., 0.}}], Infinity];
```

Now, plot the roc curves and their mean (hope they have matching dimensions) with the following code:

```
Block[{curves = 
   Values[ExtractROCPoints /@ 
     ClassifierMeasurements[iris, test, "ROCCurve"]]},

 ListStepPlot[Append[curves, Mean @ curves]]

 ]
```

We might get:

[image]

Notice that the red line is the mean!

I used a simple sampling algorithm to remedy the problem, you might choose something else:

```
ClearAll[SampleROCPoints];

SampleROCPoints[data_, n_Integer] :=
 Prepend[Block[{targetIndex, dataXUnique, target = #},
     
        dataXUnique = DeleteDuplicates @ data[[All, 1]];
     
        targetIndex = LengthWhile[dataXUnique, # <= target &];
     
        {target, Cases[data, {dataXUnique[[targetIndex]], _}][[-1, 2]]}
     
     ] & /@ Subdivide[1., n - 2], {0, 0}]
```

Now apply sampling in extracted curves (`50` is the precision):

```
Block[{curves = 
   Values[SampleROCPoints[ExtractROCPoints[#], 50] & /@ 
     ClassifierMeasurements[iris, test, "ROCCurve"]]},

 ListStepPlot[Append[curves, Mean @ curves]]

 ]
```

Which produces:

[image]

Of course, you don't want to mean all groups but it was a good example demonstrating the error and sampling.

### Update 1

Here are some tips to improve your code:

```
(* Use *)
{GroupATrain, GroupATest} = TakeDrop[RandomSample @ GroupA, 50];

(* Instead of *)
GroupATrain = RandomSample[GroupA, 50];
GroupATest = Complement[GroupA, GroupATrain];
```

- Disable `Classify` progress reporting:

```
Classify[ ... , TrainingProgressReporting -> None];
```

- You can replace `For` with `Table` and get multiple properties from `ClassifierMeasurements` (I couldn't use `"ConfusionMatrix"` which is even better), also remove `AA = {}` and similar ones before running this code:

```
{Accurate, AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC} = Transpose @ Table[

(* Code *)

Join[{CM["Accuracy", ComputeUncertainty -> True]}, 
 Length /@ 
  CM[{"Examples" -> {"A", "A"}, "Examples" -> {"A", "B"}, 
    "Examples" -> {"A", "C"}, "Examples" -> {"B", "A"}, 
    "Examples" -> {"B", "B"}, "Examples" -> {"B", "C"}, 
    "Examples" -> {"C", "A"}, "Examples" -> {"C", "B"}, 
    "Examples" -> {"C", "C"}}]]

, {z, 1, nmax}];
```

- Now that you have a `Table`, you can replace it with `ParallelTable` to run your code in parallel without doing anything.

With `nmax = 50` on my computer, it goes from 14 seconds to **1 second**!

Comment: Thank you very much, @Ben Izd.
As you say, this is giving me the mean of all the groups. It's also showing only the curves for the last iteration. However, I have been able to identify which curve belongs to which group (easy, as they are ordered alphabetically), so I just have to include this in the ```For``` loop for each group separately.

Comment: After defining empty strings for each of the groups, I can insert the following inside the ```For``` loop:     

```ROCa = AppendTo[ROCgrn, Values[SampleROCPoints[ExtractROCPoints[#], 50] & /@ 
      ClassifierMeasurements[AlgaeClass, test, "ROCCurve”]][[1]]];```    

(same for each group, only changing the number inside the [[]]).    

This will provide the ROC curve tor each group per iteration. I can then just calculate ```Mean[ROCa]```

Comment: @LNah I'm glad it works for you. `ClassifierMeasurements[ ... , "ROCCurve"]` will return an [Association](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) which have keys, I used `Values` to remove those, but you can remove it and use names instead of depending on alphabetic ordering. Also since the performance is a little heavy and you're using it inside a loop, I would recommend using a temporary variable to store `SampleROCPoints[ExtractROCPoints[#], 50] & /@ 
 ClassifierMeasurements[ ... , "ROCCurve"]` instead of recalculating it for each index.